# How to interpret $t^2$?

Tags: kinematics, time, units, dimensional-analysis

I can't think of the meaning of squaring the Time (multiplying it by itself). It makes sense in Mathematics. But how can you figure it out in nature (or physics).
As an example, the formula $$s=ut+(1/2)at^2.$$

Comment: Can you give a specific equation or example as a reference?

Comment: @Joshua, maybe he means $x(t)=(1/2)at^2$ for example for an accelerating object ?

Comment: @Nick, that is what I was thinking he meant but I am hoping for the OP to clarify in case they are thinking of something else. I can't think of anything else off the top of my head quickly though...

Comment: Is the question "What is a square-second?", an analog to when we have length squared and get a square meter? I don't think the question is why does it appear (since he says it makes sense in math) but more *what* is a square-second physically (if anything at all)... But I'm voting to close as unclear until it's clarified since we have different possible interpretations.

Comment: Possibly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48391/17609

Comment: @Joshua, Nick
You may take that equation (x(t)=(1/2)at²) as an example. How can you try to figure it out in nature (or study it) away from Maths?

Comment: I believe the OP is asking what the physical meaning of time squared is.  It is clear what the physical meaning of length squared is, namely area, but time isn't a dimension that easily lends itself to a measure or concept we have experience with in our daily life when it is squared.

Answer (score 0):

Well, think of it this way: Let's say you have a quantity that represents change over time. Could be velocity (distance travelled per unit of time), could be precipitation (inches of rain falling per hour), could be flow rate (liters per unit of time).

Now if you want to know how much stuff you get (distance travelled, inches of rain fallen, liters of water flown) after a certain amount of time, you multiply the rate with the time.

So, total distance travelled is velocity multiplied with time, total rainfall amount is rain fall rate multiplied with time, etc. etc.

Now, what if the thing that's changing over time also is something that depends on time? The easiest example here is acceleration. Acceleration tells you how much the velocity changes over time. For a car, you'd advertise how fast it can go from 0 to 100 km/h.

So, if you multiply acceleration with time, you get the resulting velocity, and to get a distance, you multiply that with time again. That's why you have "time squared"